# irc2-ircd NickServ and ChanServ

Tags: ubuntu, ip, laptop, irc

I just set up an IRC server on my laptop for the local network. however, ChanServ and NickServ don't seem to be installed/available. How might I get them?

Comment: I install an irc server today too.

I installed Dancer-IRCD following the guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dancer-IRCD which is worth considering I was installed, configured and chatting in 15 minutes. Which was nice.

Comment: and it works locally, easy to configure, and has NickServ/ChanServ?

Comment: I know nothing about IRC servers at 2pm, at 2:15pm I am talking to others on the LAN. Just copied and pasted the instructions on site. Doesn't answer your question but hope it helps you out. Try it, you can always apt-get remove it if it doesn't suit your needs. Works on two packages one that does ircd and the other to provide the services.

Comment: Added as answer. It is awesome. If only everything was so easy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment:

Try Dancer-IRCD.

Very simple to install and configure following the guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dancer-IRCD

Comment: Very smoothly answered, perfect for my needs. Great! Would upvote more!

Comment: I would like to know the traditional solution